# Создание URL сервлета

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Пытаюсь создать сервлет в Eclipse, через проект Dynamic Web Project

```
//@WebServlet("/hello_world")
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();

        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<h1> Hello World </h1>");       
        pw.println("</html>");
    }

}
```

[image: Структура проекта следующая]

В папке WEB-INF создал следующий файл web.xlm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ecoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>FirstServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello_world</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Tomcat подключен на порт 8081. Пытаюсь сделать чтобы вызов сервлета был по URL http://localhost:8081/hello_world, однако получается что необходимо вызывать через название проекта, а web.xml вообще не работает. Подскажите в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Причина проблемы:**

Это поведение по умолчанию, сервер подымается с context path, одноименным собираемому war'нику.

**Настройка Tomcat:**

Для переопределения context path, используемого по умолчанию, существует несколько вариантов, а зависимости от того, как вы выполняется deploy своего war'ника в Tomcat:

1. в `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml` затереть path: `<Context path="" docBase="MyApp"></Context>`;
2. `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/<context>.xml` со следующим содержимым: `<Context docBase="../deploy/MyApp.war"/>` (путь до вашего приложения).
3. создать файл `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` со следующим содержимым: `<Context docBase="../deploy/MyApp.war"/>` (путь до вашего приложения).

Подробнее см. [здесь](https://octopus.com/blog/defining-tomcat-context-paths) и [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application).

**Настройка в Eclipe:**

Если требуется узконаправленная настройка в рамках `Eclipse IDE`, то можно сделать [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse/32215689#32215689):

1. открыть вкладку с модулями (нажмите `F3` если у вас выбран `Tomcat` во окнке `Servers`);
2. выберите из списка нужный модуль, перейдите в режим редактирования (нажмите "edit");
3. измените `Path`.

Comment: А можно сделать как-нибудь средствами Eclipse? Т.е. при создании проекта?

Comment: @Александр, попробуйте вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215689/5872892).